# How can I see if a job failed and why?

Tags: apache-flink

How can I use `ClusterClient` to check if a job failed and why?

`ClusterClient#getJobStatus` may seem like a good first candidate but it only says if the job failed without any information regarding the exceptions.

The submission of the job is being done with a detached client therefore waiting for its `ClusterClient#run` to return a `JobExecutionResult` is not an option.

I've also tried 
`RestClusterClient#retrieveJob` also does not work, failing with:

> org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobRetrievalException: Couldn't
>   retrieve leading JobManager.  at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobListeningContext.getJobManager(JobListeningContext.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobListeningContext.getClassLoader(JobListeningContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.retrieveJob(ClusterClient.java:586)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.LeaderRetrievalException:
>   Could not retrieve the leader gateway.    at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils.retrieveLeaderGateway(LeaderRetrievalUtils.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobListeningContext.getJobManager(JobListeningContext.java:152)
>     ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures
>   timed out after [10000 milliseconds]  at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
>     at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
>     at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)    at
>   scala.concurrent.Await.result(package.scala)  at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils.retrieveLeaderGateway(LeaderRetrievalUtils.java:80)
>     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [NewClusterClient#requestJobResult](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/NewClusterClient.html#requestJobResult-org.apache.flink.api.common.JobID-) which can be done using a  `RestClusterClient`.